# Can't build Qt 4.8 under OS X Leopard (10.5)

Tags: qt

Using these separate configurations:

```
./configure -platform macx-g++ -arch x86
./configure -platform macx-g++ -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk -release
```

When used under OS X Leopard (10.5), I am getting the following build errors when trying to make QT 4.8:

```
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:50:
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:50:
error: abstract declarator ‘_CALayerTransaction*’ used as declaration
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:50:
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘[’ token
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:50:
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:50:
error: abstract declarator ‘_CALayerTransaction*’ used as declaration
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CALayer.h:50:
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘[’ token
platform/graphics/mac/MediaPlayerPrivateQTKit.mm: In static member
function ‘static void
WebCore::MediaPlayerPrivateQTKit::getSitesInMediaCache(WTF::Vector<WTF::String,
0ul>&)’:
platform/graphics/mac/MediaPlayerPrivateQTKit.mm:1514: warning: Mac OS
X version 10.5 or later is needed for use of
foreach-collection-statement
lipo: can't open input file:
/var/folders/kW/kWtAUN43HtqED7ITylqlo++++TM/-Tmp-//ccbBnUJg.out (No
such file or directory)
make[2]: *** [.obj/release-shared/MediaPlayerPrivateQTKit.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [sub-WebCore-make_default-ordered] Error 2
make: *** [sub-webkit-make_default-ordered] Error 2
```

Ideas will be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug in Qt 4.8: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-23258

You will need to apply the patch included in the report or wait for Qt to fix it.

Comment: the bug refers building under 10.6 (Snow Leopard). I am trying to build on 10.5 (Leopard). thanks though.

Comment: It's the SDK used that matters.